# Post Apocalyptic building

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a post apocalyptic building, so I tried to follow this 
tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNba2oEij2c, but it's not working.
I believe I did everything that was done in the video, but nothing happens in my building.
To create a building, create a floor and then use the array for other floors. So, following the video I duplicated the building, subdivided it and applied it to a modifier wirframe (although I didn't understand the reason for that). After adding a fractal cube and applying a boolean modifier to the building and changing the display of the cube viewport display to bounds

[image]

[image]

I have no idea how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to watch your youtube video. Why won't you try explaining your problem using your words. I often find that when I try to explain something, I figure it out myself.

Comment: The video is not mine, it's a 1 minute tutorial that I tried to follow and it didn't work out.

Comment: I gathered as much. Please explain the problem to us from the video. It's the nice thing to do.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain, I apologize.
To create a building, create a floor and then use the array for other floors.
So, following the video I duplicated the building, subdivided it and applied it to a modifier wirframe (although I didn't understand the reason for that). After adding a fractal cube and applying a boolean modifier to the building and changing the display of the cube viewport display to bounds

Comment: Please add this info to your question post; as you might have noticed it doesn't fit in a comment due to the character limit. It's also generally good practice to put all relevant information in the question post and not in a comment :)

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: What do you want to see happen?

Comment: he wants to make a boolean

Comment: I added the file to download as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to say this but it appears that you have modeled your house wrong. In what way, I cannot say. It has some "impossible" faces. This can be fixed by going to mesh/Clean Up/Degenrate Dissolve in Edit mode.

Please mark this answer as accepted if you are satisfied.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much !!!! Helped me a lot!